# Adding text awkwardly changes size of button?

Tags: html, css

In the following code, on hovering over the green button, the blue bar appears.

But when I write the words "About Me" on the `about_button` div (ie the green button), the shape of the button changes.

How can I successfully write "About Me" on the green button without spoiling the shape of the button?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
p {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
#page1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #77d47f;
}
#about {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  width: 504px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#about_button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
#about_text {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translateX(-450px);
  overflow: hidden;
}
#about {
  top: 10%;
}
#about_button:hover + #about_text {
  transform: translateX(-4px);
}
```

```html
<div id="page1">
  <div id="about">
    <div id="about_button"></div>
    <div id="about_text">
      <p>Hi, I am a Computer Science student. I am interested in designing</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the shape of the green square changing when adding or removing the text "About Me".

Answer (score 1):

add `vertical-align:top` to it, because `inline-block` by default has `vertical-align:baseline`

---

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
p {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
#page1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #77d47f;
}
#about {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  width: 504px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#about_button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top; /** THIS LINE */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
#about_text {
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translateX(-450px);
  overflow: hidden;
}
#about {
  top: 10%;
}
#about_button:hover + #about_text {
  transform: translateX(-4px);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="page1">
    <div id="about">
      <div id="about_button">About Me</div>
      <div id="about_text">
        <p>Hi, I am a Computer Science student. I am interested in designing</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain how did this solve the problem in little bit more detail? @dippas

Comment: @DhruvChadha as I said in my answer, the `inline-block` property if nothing as set by default the `vertical-align`  style will be `baseline`, therefore you must set it as `top` , see more info on `vertical-align`[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Comment: Then what happens to the height of the green box on adding text in case of vertical-align: baseline?

Comment: imagine this is just like positioning the button, either you positioning it at the top, as it is now or middle, or bottom or baseline, read that article I linked in my previous question.

Answer (score 1):

change `position` on `#about_button` from `relative` to `absolute`

Comment: Why is this able to solve the question? what was wrong first?

Comment: nothing was wrong, just a different way to display it. `vertical-align:top` is a fix to the wrong vertical-align which is baseline by default, as pointed bellow. More info [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/visudet.html#line-height) on why

Answer (score 0):

You have the attribute `display:inline-block` on the button, this forces the shape wrap around the content inside it. Change it to `display:block`.